# Pushing log4net files to ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, log4net

I have written c# WebAPI and want to use log4net to logs requests to the files. After the log is written to the log file I would like to push those log files (will capture all the requests using DelegateHandler) to ElasticSearch. I have searched everywhere but I am unable to find a solution to my problem. Following is the log4net.config file that I have ( ElasticAppender doesnt work)

```
   <log4net>
     <root>
       <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
       <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearchAppender" />
     </root>
     <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
       <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs/API_.log" />
       <appendToFile value="true" />
       <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
       <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
       <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
       <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
       <staticLogFileName value="false" />
       <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.fff}, %message%newline" />
       </layout>
       <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
          <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
          <levelMax value="ERROR" />
       </filter>
     </appender>
     <appender name="ElasticSearchAppender" type="log4net.ElasticSearch.ElasticSearchAppender, log4stash">
       <Server>elasticnode01</Server>
       <Port>9200</Port>
       <IndexName>apilogentry</IndexName>
       <ElasticFilters>
          <Filter type="log4net.ElasticSearch.Filters.RenameKeyFilter, log4stash">
            <Key>processId</Key>
            <RenameTo>ServiceName</RenameTo>
          </Filter>
          <Filter type="log4net.ElasticSearch.Filters.RenameKeyFilter, log4stash">
            <Key>Message</Key>
            <RenameTo>message</RenameTo>
         </Filter>
         <Grok>
            <SourceKey>message</SourceKey>
            <Pattern>%{NUMBER:ResponseCode} %{WORD:Method} %{URIPATHPARAM:Url} %{NUMBER:ElapsedMls} %{GREEDYDATA:StatusMessage}</Pattern>
         </Grok>
      </ElasticFilters>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="ERROR" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
 </log4net>
```

Here is the class that I am using to collect the data (that I would like log).

```
  public class ApiLogEntry
{
    public long ApiLogEntryId { get; set; }             // The (database) ID for the API log entry.
    public string Application { get; set; }             // The application that made the request.
    public string User { get; set; }                    // The user that made the request.
    public string Machine { get; set; }                 // The machine that made the request.
    public string RequestIpAddress { get; set; }        // The IP address that made the request.
    public string RequestContentType { get; set; }      // The request content type.
    public string RequestContentBody { get; set; }      // The request content body.
    public string RequestUri { get; set; }              // The request URI.
    public string RequestMethod { get; set; }           // The request method (GET, POST, etc).
    public string RequestRouteTemplate { get; set; }    // The request route template.
    public string RequestRouteData { get; set; }        // The request route data.
    public string RequestHeaders { get; set; }          // The request headers.
    public DateTime? RequestTimestamp { get; set; }     // The request timestamp.
    public string ResponseContentType { get; set; }     // The response content type.
    public string ResponseContentBody { get; set; }     // The response content body.
    public int? ResponseStatusCode { get; set; }        // The response status code.
    public string ResponseHeaders { get; set; }         // The response headers.
    public DateTime? ResponseTimestamp { get; set; }    // The response timestamp.
}
```

This is the class that handles all the HTTP requests and should log the information. Right now the info is being logged to files.

```
public class ApiLogHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    ILogger _logger;
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var apiLogEntry = CreateApiLogEntryWithRequestData(request);
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    apiLogEntry.RequestContentBody = task.Result;
                }, cancellationToken);
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                var response = task.Result;

                // Update the API log entry with response info
                apiLogEntry.ResponseStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                apiLogEntry.ResponseTimestamp = DateTime.Now;

                if (response.Content != null)
                {
                  //  apiLogEntry.ResponseContentBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    apiLogEntry.ResponseContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
                    apiLogEntry.ResponseHeaders = SerializeHeaders(response.Content.Headers);
                }

                // TODO: Save the API log entry to the database


                _logger.Info(apiLogEntry);

                return response;
            }, cancellationToken);
    }

    private ApiLogEntry CreateApiLogEntryWithRequestData(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var context = ((HttpContextBase)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]);
        var routeData = request.GetRouteData();

        return new ApiLogEntry
        {
            Application = "Search.API",
            User = context.User.Identity.Name,
            Machine = Environment.MachineName,
            RequestContentType = context.Request.ContentType,
            RequestRouteTemplate = routeData.Route.RouteTemplate,
            //RequestRouteData = SerializeRouteData(routeData),
            RequestIpAddress = context.Request.UserHostAddress,
            RequestMethod = request.Method.Method,
            RequestHeaders = SerializeHeaders(request.Headers),
            RequestTimestamp = DateTime.Now,
            RequestUri = request.RequestUri.ToString()
        };
    }

    private string SerializeRouteData(IHttpRouteData routeData)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(routeData, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });

        //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(routeData, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        //{
        //    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        //});
    }

    private string SerializeHeaders(HttpHeaders headers)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in headers.ToList())
        {
            if (item.Value != null)
            {
                var header = String.Empty;
                foreach (var value in item.Value)
                {
                    header += value + " ";
                }

                // Trim the trailing space and add item to the dictionary
                header = header.TrimEnd(" ".ToCharArray());
                dict.Add(item.Key, header);
            }
        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);
    }

    public ApiLogHandler(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

How do I get the output from these files to ElasticSearch? I have read about FileBeat and logstash but not sure how to get this all running. Anyone has any ideas on what I might be missing? (I know grok entry in log4net.config isnt right ( I am trying to map to ApiLogEntry class but have no idea how to proceed).

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for the Elastic Search Log4Net appender [does not recommend using this approach in production](https://github.com/bruno-garcia/log4net.ElasticSearch/wiki/05-Performance-Considerations).

What it does recommend is using [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.9/filebeat-installation-configuration.html) to push the log file data via [LogStash](https://www.elastic.co/logstash) (for data transformation/parsing) into an Elastic Search database.  At the time of writing all of these components could be used freely on a [self hosted Basic installation](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions).

Answer (score 4):

Follow the documentation of 
[Log4net.ElasticSearch NuGet Lib](https://github.com/jptoto/log4net.ElasticSearch) and you should be able to accomplish your goal.

Comment: this doesnt look like an answer.this should be in comment

Comment: @TarangP I don't have 50 reputations in order to add a comment on the original question. I added this as an answer as it might help someone.

Comment: helped me thanks m. abouzeid